# "Operation not permitted" while trying to run command line in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'm building a MACOS app to watch processes/threads running on the computer. I wrote the following function to execute commands:

```
func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
  let task = Process()
  let pipe = Pipe()

  task.standardOutput = pipe
  task.standardError = pipe
  task.arguments = ["-c", command]
  task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
  task.standardInput = nil
  task.launch()

  let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
  let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

  return output
}
```

The function above works well when I run commands like "ls -a" but I get an **zsh:1: operation not permitted: ps** if I try to run something like "ps x".

I saw some related posts talking about the entitlement file, so I also included that in my project:

[image]

However, it is still not working for me. Do you guys have any ideas about what else I should try?

Comment: This works fine for me in a SwiftUI macOS project with no special entitlements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for some of your replies, once I set "App Sandbox" to "No" on my entitlement file, everything worked.

[image]

I was trying to create a new entitlement file instead of using the existing one. That was my main mistake.